# Do I have to log in every time when testing a logged in user with Cucumber & Devise gems?

Tags: testing, authentication, devise, cucumber, bdd

I want to write up a scenario that looks something like:

```
Given I am logged in
And I am on my profile page
Then I see my name
```

For the "Given I am logged in" - do I need to write something like:

```
  When I go to the log in page
  And I fill in "user_username" with "test" 
  And I fill in "user_password" with "invalid password"
  And I press "Sign in"
```

Question is: does the test have to go through the login scenario every time I test a logged in user functionality?

EDIT:
Note that I am using the Devise gem. I am not sure how to log in the user directly since the user session, cookies, etc have to be set

Answer (score 1):

I would write a step definition to handle the login instead of a scenario.

This step definition can then put the cookies in the cookie jar for subsequent use.

If you store the cookiejars in a hashmap keyed on the test users then the method can be smart enough to only log in when needen and reuse a session if one is still available. This can save a lot of time in the tests at the expense of not having completely independent tests, since now they're coupled through the session data on the server. The session can always be cleared by logging out before logging in again.